# display dialog box on runtime on asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

hey i am new to programming and am working on asp.net for my college work. just want to ask how could i display values on run time say

```
 public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
      for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
      {
       //required code here
      }
    }
  }
```

i want this code to display 0 on dialog box and when i pressed enter it displays 1,2,...

this may be a stupid question sorry for it

i tried using Alert.Show(); but it only displayed the last value; what i wanted is to show 0 and after i clicked ok to display 1 then 2 and so on

Comment: ASP.NET cannot display a dialog box as a client app would.  You can only do what a browser permits.  If you really want a box to popup you could look into javascript's `alert()` function, but you'll need to make the page print javascript code that will execute on the client.

Comment: web applications are stateless...the typical variables in a asp.net program only have life as long as the request. Each time a new request hits the server new set of variables are created and destroyed once the request is served; the cycle goes on...the dialog boxes scenario you require cannot be satisfied by web applications for these obvious reasons...

Comment: i tried using Alert.Show(); but it only displayed the last value; what i wanted is to show 0 and after i clicked ok to display 1 then 2 and so on

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

C#

```
public void Message(string msg)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "msgid", "alert('" + msg + "')", true);
}

Message("Here comes the message");
```

VB.NET

```
Public Sub Message(msg as String)
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "msgid", "alert('" & msg & "')", true)
End Sub

Message("Here comes the message")
```